# Creating a restricted user from Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup, kiosk

I would like to create restricted user account in my setup script for a kiosk application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the [`NetUserAdd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) direct from (Unicode) Inno Setup or write a small wrapper DLL/program that does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code above is probably best, but I like the command-line since it can go easily under the [run] section without needing to write a method and hook it all up, etc.  It does have limitations though.

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\net.exe Parameters: user UserName Pwd /add
```